# Ecommerce Product HTML Page Wrapper

Tags: php, html, parsing, e-commerce

I need a lot of product information for my research, such as the price, category, rating, user reviews and so on. And they'd better come from different sources (Amazon, ebay etc.). I've crawled megabytes HTML pages. So now I wonder if there's any existing universal (to some degree) parser library that can parse these raw html pages from different ecommerce websites.

I know this requirement maybe too specific, but I just need a basis first so that I can tailor it to my specific use. Hopefully, the input is a HTML file describing the product, and the output is an associative array like: `{'price' => $price, 'rating' => $rating, 'category' => $category, ...}.` I think such wrappers may need training data to do some kind of learning, which is okay. That would be better if it's a PHP library because my crawler is written in PHP. Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.